# Laravel Connection for Sub-query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.1.

I'm trying to get a list of records from a table, where the userid doesn't exists as id in the user table.

I'm trying to create a query with a sub-select in it. Both the main query and the sub-select need to use the non-default connection.

I have tried:

```
    DB::connection('database')
        ->table('table')
        ->whereNotIn('userid', function($query)
        {
            $query->select('id')
                ->from('user');
        })->get();
```

When I print out the sql and run it in MySQL workbench, I get the expected result.
But I get the feeling that the sub-select is being done on the default connection instead of the connection I'm trying to use.

Please help.

Comment: Both use the same object, so both use the same connection.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk, you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a test and it seems it is working fine. In case of your query also `$query->select('id')->from('user');` will be run on `database` connection.

You can test it on your own. In `from('user')` you should put name of table that does exists for default connection and doesn't exist in `database` connection. If subquery would use default connection application shouldn't throw any exception but in fact it does because this table doesn't exist in `database` connection

Comment: I have tried adding connection into the sub-query in that way. But I get the error 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::connection()'

Comment: I had another look at my code. It was another part of the code that was causing the problem.